# Google Play reminder of deadline for resolving Apache Cordova vulnerabilities

Tags: android, apache, cordova, warnings

Hi I have received the following notification from google. Will google unpublish or remove the existing app from play store which were developed using pre 3.5.1 cordova?

We have a app on play store with vulnerable cordova but we are not planning to publish any updates to this app in near future. We have decided to develop a native app and move away from cordova. This might take few months but we will eventually replace it with a native app. So we dont have any plans to push updates to the cordova app.

In that case are we still forced to upgrade the cordova or we can leave the app as it is and ignore the warning. I am just not sure if Google will remove/delete the app after 31st August if it is not updated.

Thanks any help will be appreciated.

Hello Google Play Developer,

This is your final warning that your app(s), including those listed at the end of this email, are built on a version of Apache Cordova that contains security vulnerabilities. If you have over 20 apps in your account, please see the Developer Console for the full list of affected apps.

Please migrate your app(s) to Apache Cordova v.3.5.1 or higher as soon as possible. Beginning 8/31/15, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps and updates that use pre-3.5.1 versions of Apache Cordova (see below for details).

The vulnerabilities include a high severity cross-application scripting (XAS) vulnerability. Under certain circumstances, susceptible apps could be remotely exploited to steal sensitive information, such as user login credentials.

For guidance on upgrading Apache Cordova and for more information about the vulnerabilities, please see Apache Cordova’s security bulletin. For other technical questions about Apache Cordova, you can post to https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions and use the tags “android-security” and “cordova.”

To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of the app(s) to the Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app hasn’t been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning.

On 8/31/15, we will not accept app updates containing pre-3.5.1 versions of Apache Cordova. In addition, we will reject new apps containing pre-3.5.1 versions of Apache Cordova.

While these specific issues may not affect every app that uses Apache Cordova versions prior to 3.5.1, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Apps with vulnerabilities that expose users to risk of compromise may be considered dangerous products in violation of the Content Policy and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.

Before publishing apps, please ensure they are compliant with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Content Policy. If you feel we have sent this warning in error, contact our support team through the Google Play Developer Help Center.

Regards,

The Google Play Team

Comment: I guess words 'final warning' are quite self-explanatory? Why not just release a version with updated cordova? I am pretty sure that fixes for security vulnerabilities in SDK won't force you to change the source code. So, I can't understand why can't you dedicate 5 minutes of your time to building of the new version of the app with updated cordova? Instead you're putting your user to the risk of losing sensitive data - I totally can't understand you

Comment: And the answer to your question - yes Google will do that

Comment: @Chaosit - Is it just 5 mins? Dont I have have to update all other plugins that I have added to the project? I think the project might throw some errors when I try to build it again after upgrading the project. But I think I have no choice now rather than updating the cordova. Thanks a lot for the help.